# Jquery Scrollable Customized - Errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollable

I am using the following plugin:

flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

I've slightly customized it by removing the tabs, and using image buttons.
you can view my work here:

http://getitnow4free.com/FreeWebsite/Page2.html

If you keep hitting next template and previous template buttons in order to cycle through all of the available templates, you will notice that the templates and preview, download buttons move more and more out of place the more you cycle through them. Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it?

I also notice that when I click the preview template button for a template, it cycles on to the next template automatically. I don't want that. I would like for the template to remain in the window until next or previous is hit. Can anyone help me with these issues?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you don't need to modify this plugin. It already advances with "next" and "previous" buttons. You removed the tabs, but that wasn't really necessary. Instead, you could have set the following rule:

```
ul.tabs { display:none }
```

That would have removed the tabs for you. All that would be left is to use your own images for "next" and "previous" as opposed to the defaults.